# What's the proper way to use SignalR in NetCore Console and winform?

Tags: c#, .net-core, signalr

I need to build a proof o concept for a project, but I'm having troubles finding some good online resources as all the tutorials are just talking about webpages and so on.

I need to understand how to have a console app acting as a server/hub in SignalR and a Winform/Wpf acting like a client. 
Can anyone point me to the right direction? I'm not gonna post any code in my question just because basically I don't have nothing and I'm still trying to understand where to start. Thanks

Comment: have a look at this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1181555/SignalChat-WPF-SignalR-Chat-Application)

Comment: I have [a repo](https://github.com/Expecho/Self-Hosted-SignalR) demonstrating doing thus using .net framewrok console apps

Comment: Thanks very much both of you for the quick replay, I'll have a look now and I'll let you guys know..

Comment: @PeterBons i don't get how to send message from the server to the client..

Comment: I have updated the code and the README